# Digital Communication \$T_x\$ and \$R_x\$ for Dish - Coaxial Cable - TV Setup

Tags: communication, digital-communications, transmitter, receiver, coax

I have a question in mind regarding transmitters and receivers. Let's say we have a dish then a coaxial cable connecting our dish to the TV. Can we consider the Dish as a transmitter \$T_x\$ and the TV coaxial input as the receiver \$R_x\$ ? Will the signal passing through the coaxial cable (our channel in that case) be simply the analog electrical signal but amplified? Or is there some intermediate processing?

Comment: Satellite dishes for TVs tend to have head amplifiers.

Comment: That coax likely carries DC power, and digital control signals, as well as "TV"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing at the focus point of your satellite TV dish is called LNB; you might want to look up what that abbreviation stands for ;)

In short, amplified, pre-filtered and mixed.

Comment: Ooo that's quite interesting thank you. So lets say we are looking at the signal from the dish to the TV can we say the TV coaxial port is the receiver and the LNB is actually the transmitter of the signal at the coaxial cable ?

Comment: if you want to, yes. But, honestly, when we say "transmitter" and "receiver" we often do that to describe that a noisy, signal-altering channel happens in between. And, with good chance, we can ignore all the cable effects, so really, I'd just consider the LNB and the coax cable *part* of the receiver.